# The XML source is not well formed: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 10, position 2772. Parameter name: XML source

Tags: xml, vbscript, qtp

I am working with QTP using VBScript language.

I am trying to compare two XML and get the difference.

Getting error mentioned as follows

> The XML source is not well formed: Invalid character in the given encoding.
>   Line 10, position 2772.
>   Parameter name: XML source
>   Line (9): "objxml1.LoadFile(xmlFile1)"

My code as follows:

```vb
Dim xmlFile1, xmlFile2, objxml1, objxml2

xmlFile1 = "C:\Data\XML1.xml"
xmlFile2 = "C:\Data\XML2.xml"
Set objxml1 = XMLUtil.CreateXML()
Set objxml2 = XMLUtil.CreateXML()

objxml1.LoadFile(xmlFile1) 
objxml2.LoadFile(xmlFile2)

Result = objXML1.Compare(objXML2, objResultsXML)

If Result = 1 Then
    print "XML Files Match"
Else
    print "XML Files do not match"
    objResultsXML.SaveFile("C:\Data\xmldiff.xml")
End If
```

Comment: *"The XML source is not well formed."* What is not clear about that error?

Comment: I am trying to compare other xmls and get the results properly. But only for some specific xmls I am getting this error.

Comment: Those. XML. Files. Are. Malformed.

Comment: I have verified my XML with NOTEPAD++  using "Check XML Syntax now" and got the message as NO error detected. So XML is not Malformed

Comment: What is the encoding format of your xml files? UTF or Ansi?

Comment: UFT Automation Tool

Comment: Malformed doesn't just mean the structure has to be correct, the encoding has to be correct as well.

Comment: How to verify encoding of xml is correct or not?

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comments, your original XML files that you are trying to read in are not properly formed XML files, and so the lines that read the file into your program are failing.
You cannot read the XML files in to compare them if they are not valid XML files to start with.  Your code is not even getting to the .Compare method.

Comment: Could you please suggest me How to verify XML is well formed before working with QTP.?